# CORS Issue when Making Cross-Origin Requests on NODEJS

Tags: node.js, cors, backend

I'm facing a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue in my application. I recently created an application following the same steps as a previous one I made, but now I'm having difficulties with CORS.

The specific error I receive is: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3333/sessions' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I've tried to solve the problem by installing the CORS package in my backend and correctly configuring the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to allow requests from the origin "http://localhost:5173", but the error still persists.

My current backend configuration is as follows:

```
require("express-async-errors");
const express = require('express');
const AppError = require("./utils/AppError");
const database = require("./database/sqlite");
const uploadConfig = require("./configs/upload");
const cors = require("cors");

database();

const routes = require("./routes");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(routes);

app.use(cors());

app.use((error, request, response, next) => {
    if(error instanceof AppError) {
        return response.status(error.statusCode).json({
            status: "error",
            message: error.message
        });
    }   
    
    console.error(error)

    return response.status(500).json({
        status: "error",
        message: "Internal server error"
    });
});

app.use("/files", express.static(uploadConfig.UPLOADS_FOLDER));

const PORT = 3333
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on Port ${PORT}`))
```

I'm running the server on port 3333, and my front-end application is running on http://localhost:5173.

I would like to understand why I'm facing this CORS issue, even though I'm following the same steps that worked in a previous application. Additionally, I would like to know if there's anything else I can do to resolve this problem.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!

My code on github to my backend : https://github.com/marcelo-dos-santos/api_rocketfilms

my code on github to my frontend : https://github.com/marcelo-dos-santos/frontend-rocketfilms

Comment: Why are you calling `app.use` twice for CORS?

Comment: i was testing using allowedHeaders, but it didn't work, I already corrected it in the code

Comment: Try adding `app.use(cors())` at the top, before adding any other middle ware.

Comment: Adding app.use at the top before other middleware WORKED! THANKS!!